# Identity Server MVC Quickstart does not log in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to get the IdentityServer with EF sample to run but am running into a strange problem. When I click on the 'Secure' tab in the MVC home page, it takes me to the IS4 login. However after I click log in, I get redirected back to the login page. I have verified that the User exists in the database. Here are the logs I get making these requests:

```
2017-12-16 17:21:33.539 -04:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default scheme for authentication
2017-12-16 17:21:33.583 -04:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default scheme for sign-in
2017-12-16 17:21:33.585 -04:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default scheme for sign-out
2017-12-16 17:21:33.585 -04:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default scheme for challenge
2017-12-16 17:21:33.586 -04:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default scheme for forbid
2017-12-16 17:21:33.720 -04:00 [DBG] Starting token cleanup
2017-12-16 17:21:36.466 -04:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
2017-12-16 17:21:36.499 -04:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
2017-12-16 17:21:36.502 -04:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
2017-12-16 17:21:36.514 -04:00 [DBG] Start authorize request
2017-12-16 17:21:36.531 -04:00 [DBG] No user present in authorize request
2017-12-16 17:21:36.539 -04:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2017-12-16 17:21:37.900 -04:00 [DBG] mvc found in database: true
2017-12-16 17:21:37.915 -04:00 [DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
2017-12-16 17:21:37.917 -04:00 [DBG] No PKCE used.
2017-12-16 17:21:38.017 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:21:38.345 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["api1"] API scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:21:38.370 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:21:38.382 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["api1"] API scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:21:38.398 -04:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2017-12-16 17:21:38.495 -04:00 [INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{
"ClientId": "mvc",
"ClientName": "MVC Client",
"RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
"AllowedRedirectUris": [
"http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"
],
"SubjectId": "anonymous",
"ResponseType": "code id_token",
"ResponseMode": "form_post",
"GrantType": "hybrid",
"RequestedScopes": "openid profile api1 offline_access",
"State": "CfDJ8OjFhWHnTLBEporSKt_A6SqBDQbwqg26gGARan3UYPBz6RCfh0BazL0IWdxWjjgzJU7Qknp01KHWRMy_VSdJ8H7Jbbwsxhj2c5JZ8Jk5NFb-EASixxCCE3UH19kdWu9H_MpW33PqRVIAkQGuk7lVLmaRa85bWMYEMIh8N5zUbXjDCi90qj_lokqwxMmlZ3avfgVo3NaTEGh94CZzvEa5I33D2WbSx1h4xA2SVOZqJNWZESWCQazUuQt8745dUVe0fx8fecSDBlZJK2F_QNh5I-6FPw7uCrlZUKYNhbkWUdyvNazMIVQIrxq8RUcjgfL-_cYIVyPi5cVUPtHg90uuNJ4",
"Nonce": "636490560962891702.OGQ5ZjE0OGQtN2Y1My00NzRhLTg0MjktZWFkMTU2YmViODhjMDk2YTc0M2YtNGY1MC00M2JiLTlhNjQtN2RjMjE1NDZmYzJh",
"Raw": {
"client_id": "mvc",
"redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
"response_type": "code id_token",
"scope": "openid profile api1 offline_access",
"response_mode": "form_post",
"nonce": "636490560962891702.OGQ5ZjE0OGQtN2Y1My00NzRhLTg0MjktZWFkMTU2YmViODhjMDk2YTc0M2YtNGY1MC00M2JiLTlhNjQtN2RjMjE1NDZmYzJh",
"state": "CfDJ8OjFhWHnTLBEporSKt_A6SqBDQbwqg26gGARan3UYPBz6RCfh0BazL0IWdxWjjgzJU7Qknp01KHWRMy_VSdJ8H7Jbbwsxhj2c5JZ8Jk5NFb-EASixxCCE3UH19kdWu9H_MpW33PqRVIAkQGuk7lVLmaRa85bWMYEMIh8N5zUbXjDCi90qj_lokqwxMmlZ3avfgVo3NaTEGh94CZzvEa5I33D2WbSx1h4xA2SVOZqJNWZESWCQazUuQt8745dUVe0fx8fecSDBlZJK2F_QNh5I-6FPw7uCrlZUKYNhbkWUdyvNazMIVQIrxq8RUcjgfL-_cYIVyPi5cVUPtHg90uuNJ4",
"x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
"x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0"
}
}
2017-12-16 17:21:38.516 -04:00 [INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated
2017-12-16 17:21:38.742 -04:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
2017-12-16 17:21:38.759 -04:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2017-12-16 17:21:38.771 -04:00 [DBG] mvc found in database: true
2017-12-16 17:21:38.771 -04:00 [DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
2017-12-16 17:21:38.774 -04:00 [DBG] No PKCE used.
2017-12-16 17:21:38.781 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:21:38.791 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["api1"] API scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:21:38.801 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:21:38.810 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["api1"] API scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:21:38.812 -04:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2017-12-16 17:22:00.441 -04:00 [DBG] Augmenting SignInContext
2017-12-16 17:22:00.455 -04:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
2017-12-16 17:22:00.461 -04:00 [INF] User logged in.
2017-12-16 17:22:00.473 -04:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/authorize/callback matched to endpoint type Authorize
2017-12-16 17:22:00.477 -04:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
2017-12-16 17:22:00.479 -04:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
2017-12-16 17:22:00.489 -04:00 [DBG] Start authorize callback request
2017-12-16 17:22:00.495 -04:00 [DBG] No user present in authorize request
2017-12-16 17:22:00.496 -04:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2017-12-16 17:22:00.510 -04:00 [DBG] mvc found in database: true
2017-12-16 17:22:00.510 -04:00 [DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
2017-12-16 17:22:00.515 -04:00 [DBG] No PKCE used.
2017-12-16 17:22:00.527 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:22:00.537 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["api1"] API scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:22:00.544 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:22:00.554 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["api1"] API scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:22:00.556 -04:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2017-12-16 17:22:00.562 -04:00 [INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{
"ClientId": "mvc",
"ClientName": "MVC Client",
"RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
"AllowedRedirectUris": [
"http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"
],
"SubjectId": "anonymous",
"ResponseType": "code id_token",
"ResponseMode": "form_post",
"GrantType": "hybrid",
"RequestedScopes": "openid profile api1 offline_access",
"State": "CfDJ8OjFhWHnTLBEporSKt_A6SqBDQbwqg26gGARan3UYPBz6RCfh0BazL0IWdxWjjgzJU7Qknp01KHWRMy_VSdJ8H7Jbbwsxhj2c5JZ8Jk5NFb-EASixxCCE3UH19kdWu9H_MpW33PqRVIAkQGuk7lVLmaRa85bWMYEMIh8N5zUbXjDCi90qj_lokqwxMmlZ3avfgVo3NaTEGh94CZzvEa5I33D2WbSx1h4xA2SVOZqJNWZESWCQazUuQt8745dUVe0fx8fecSDBlZJK2F_QNh5I-6FPw7uCrlZUKYNhbkWUdyvNazMIVQIrxq8RUcjgfL-_cYIVyPi5cVUPtHg90uuNJ4",
"Nonce": "636490560962891702.OGQ5ZjE0OGQtN2Y1My00NzRhLTg0MjktZWFkMTU2YmViODhjMDk2YTc0M2YtNGY1MC00M2JiLTlhNjQtN2RjMjE1NDZmYzJh",
"Raw": {
"client_id": "mvc",
"redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
"response_type": "code id_token",
"scope": "openid profile api1 offline_access",
"response_mode": "form_post",
"nonce": "636490560962891702.OGQ5ZjE0OGQtN2Y1My00NzRhLTg0MjktZWFkMTU2YmViODhjMDk2YTc0M2YtNGY1MC00M2JiLTlhNjQtN2RjMjE1NDZmYzJh",
"state": "CfDJ8OjFhWHnTLBEporSKt_A6SqBDQbwqg26gGARan3UYPBz6RCfh0BazL0IWdxWjjgzJU7Qknp01KHWRMy_VSdJ8H7Jbbwsxhj2c5JZ8Jk5NFb-EASixxCCE3UH19kdWu9H_MpW33PqRVIAkQGuk7lVLmaRa85bWMYEMIh8N5zUbXjDCi90qj_lokqwxMmlZ3avfgVo3NaTEGh94CZzvEa5I33D2WbSx1h4xA2SVOZqJNWZESWCQazUuQt8745dUVe0fx8fecSDBlZJK2F_QNh5I-6FPw7uCrlZUKYNhbkWUdyvNazMIVQIrxq8RUcjgfL-_cYIVyPi5cVUPtHg90uuNJ4",
"x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
"x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0"
}
}
2017-12-16 17:22:00.570 -04:00 [INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated
2017-12-16 17:22:00.580 -04:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
2017-12-16 17:22:00.581 -04:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2017-12-16 17:22:00.591 -04:00 [DBG] mvc found in database: true
2017-12-16 17:22:00.592 -04:00 [DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
2017-12-16 17:22:00.593 -04:00 [DBG] No PKCE used.
2017-12-16 17:22:00.601 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:22:00.610 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["api1"] API scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:22:00.617 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:22:00.626 -04:00 [DBG] Found ["api1"] API scopes in database
2017-12-16 17:22:00.627 -04:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2017-12-16 17:22:03.763 -04:00 [INF] Clearing 0 tokens
2017-12-16 17:22:07.013 -04:00 [DBG] TaskCanceledException. Exiting.
2017-12-16 17:22:07.040 -04:00 [DBG] Stopping token cleanup
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by clearing all my Cookies belonging to the domain of my Identity server (in my case localhost:5000)